# How to see my raw http post *from* java/jboss?

Tags: java, http, jboss

I have a HTTP POST that I do in my java program, running on JBoss, and I would like to intercept it and see the raw request.

I did try [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4), as in many answers here, but looks like it will only show the requests from the browser to my JBoss, not from my JBoss/Java to outside.

Any idea?

Comment: Give a try with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests)

Comment: Fiddler can be man-in-middle for between any client and server. In this case, your Java program is the client, so just tell your Java program to send POST to Fiddler, and setup Fiddler to forward to where it was supposed to go.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen you mean, by posting on it instead of trying to intercept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on Linux, you can try tcpdump with the following options.

```
sudo tcpdump -An -s 0 -i any 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

If you're on Windows, then [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) is probably your best bet.